# Measure of a disjoint non-countable union

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a measure space and $I$ a non-countable set. If $\{A_i\}_{i \in I} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$  are disjoint and such that $\forall i \in I : \mu(A_i) \in (0,\infty)$ then $\mu(\cup_{i \in I} A_i)= +\infty$

I have trying to prove this in order to use it for another proof but I have no idea on how to proceed. A friend has tried to prove it by contraposition supossing that if an infinite union has finite measure it has to be countable, but we don't get to it by this way.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are the sets disjoint? You stated that in the title, but not in the formal statement of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, they are disjoint, my mistake

Comment: Actually it is not true in general because it might be that $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says "disjoint" but your question does not. I assume the $A_i$ are disjoint.

We work by contradiction. Let $A=\cup_{i\in I}A_i$ and assume $\mu(A)<\infty$.

Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $T_n=\{i\in I:\mu(A_i)>1/n\}$. Then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty T_n=I$.

Each $T_n$ must be finite. Indeed, if $|T_n|>n\mu(A)$, then we can choose a finite subset $G$ of $T_n$ with $|G|>n\mu(A)$. Then $\cup_{i\in G}A_i\subset A$ and $$\mu(A) \geqslant \mu\bigl(\bigcup_{i\in G}A_i\bigr)=\sum_{i\in G}\mu(A_i)>|G|/n>\mu(A),$$ a contradiction. We used disjointness to deduce that $\mu(\cup_{i\in G}A_i)=\sum_{i\in G}\mu(A_i)$.

So each $T_n$ is finite, and $I=\cup_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ is countable.

A similar idea can be used to show that not only does $A$ have infinite measure, but it cannot even be $\sigma$-finite. That is, there cannot exist measurable $B_1,B_2,\ldots$ such that $\mu(B_n)<\infty$ and $A=\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. Indeed, we can assume (by replacing $B_m$ with $B_1\cup\ldots\cup B_m$) assume that $B_1\subset B_2\subset \ldots$. Define $T_{m,n}=\{i\in I:\mu(A_i\cap B_m)>1/n\}$. Then $I=\cup_{m,n}T_{m,n}$ and each $T_{m,n}$ must be finite.

This can be used to show, for example, that there cannot be an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint, Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ each of which has positive measure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If for every positive integer $n$ we define:$$I_n:=\left\{i\in I\mid \mu(A_i)>\frac1n\right\}$$
then $I=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ imlying that for at least one $n$ the set $I_n$ must be uncountable.

Then let $J$ be an infinite and countable subset of this $I_n$ and define $B=\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i$.

Then clearly $B$ is a measurable set with $\mu(B)=\infty$ and of course we will have $\mu(C)=\infty$ for *every* measurable set $C$ that contains $B$ as a subset.

Here $B\subseteq A:=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ so if $A$ is measurable (this extra condition must be mentioned because $\mu$ is not defined on non-measurable sets) then $\mu(A)=\infty$.